# Determinants to solve a system

Tags: determinant, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

I was reading a book on Calculus when I came across this:

$$\begin{cases}
v+\ln(u)=xy \\
u+\ln(v)=x-y \\
\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
\frac1u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=y \\
\frac1v\frac{\partial v} {\partial x} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1 \\
\end{cases}$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{ \begin{vmatrix} yu & u \\ v & 1 \\ \end{vmatrix} }{\begin{vmatrix} 1 & u \\ v & 1 \\ \end{vmatrix} }=\frac{u(y-v)}{1-uv}$$

I can get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ myself, but upon reaching the second system of equations I would have solved it with substitution. His use of determinants baffles me, and I have no form of Googling this. My questions are:

What is the name of this technique?

How were the elements of the matrix calculated?

A proof or a link to one would be a nice bonus as well.

Comment: this is the standard Cramers rule formula for the solution of a linear system of equations. Think of the derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{ \partial x}, \frac{\partial v}{ \partial x}$ as variables to be solved for in the linear system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This technique is called [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

Comment: Congratulations, Sami!!!! Welcome to the 100K club!! ;-)

Comment: So how does it feel to be part of "the club"? ;-)